# Why clean a pot (used to cook rice) with cold water?

Tags: cleaning, rice

Some people have told me that it's better to clean a dirty pot (used to cook rice) with cold water, rather than the hot water I use for all the other dishes.  What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Note this is also true with wheat flour mixtures as well, but the reason is different. Cold water will cause the gluten to contract and release its grip from the bowl, making it easier to clean.

Comment: And for the same reason, wash your hands with cold water if you've got (wheat based) dough stuck to them. (Or do what we do; grab some more flour and rub your hands together. Voila
! Clean.)

Comment: I have found when cleaning pots and pans with starch that it dissolves and washes away faster in hot water & dish soap. It just does. I don't know what science has to say about that but that's what I have observed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Residual starches swell up and get sticky in hot water.  This doesn't happen with cold water -- In the time it takes to wash a pot.